# It is made in Japan , But It is from USA

Tags: grammar

It is made in Japan , But It is from USA.
1.Can i write? -> It is made in Japan which is from USA.
2.Which one is correct ? ->
   A.It was made...
   B.It is made...

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Raymond.  Can you give an example of something that was made in Japan but is from USA? How can that happen? Do you mean that you bought it in USA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning is unclear, but the form with "which" is certainly not what you mean.
"It is made in Japan, which is from the USA." says that "Japan is from the USA".

Your first attempt was much better, but rather than "from the USA" you could say "I bought it in the USA".

> It was made in Japan, but I bought it in the USA.

If you are talking about a specific item  say "It was made in Japan".  If you are talking about a general product (that is still being produced) "It is made"

> Sake is made in Japan.
>   This bottle of sake was made in Japan, but I bought it in the USA.

Comment: Another possibility is that it is/was made in a Japanese factory owned by a US company, of which there are far fewer than Chinese factories owned by US companied. But until Raymond clarifies, we're all just guessing.